# PHP - Extract content from atributte

Tags: php, html, dom, extract

i have problem. I need extract content from atributte content:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="KEYWORDS">
<meta name="description" content="THIS TEXT"> 
</head>
```

I use this PHP code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
       echo $tag->getAttribute('content');

        }
```

but the code find only first appearance of atributte content,
but i need the second apperance atributte content....

Comment: For me it works as provided.

Comment: yes it's working here too

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');
foreach ($elements as $child) {
    echo $child->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: This show me error: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <head> tag in Entity, line: 1.   The source code is not HTML valid, it is not my source code.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
<?php
$nodes = $xml->getElementsByTagName ("meta");

$nodeListLength = $nodes->length; 
for ($i = 0; $i < $nodeListLength; $i ++)
{
   $node = $nodes->item($i)->getAttribute('content');
}
?>
```

Comment: This don´t work. I think that this code run only with HTML valid pages.

Comment: i dont think so, anyways refer [this](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)